# Best practice for s3 key naming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, directory, naming-conventions

I have some Records in an app that can be named from 000000-999999 .

I am storing attachments for these records in an S3 Bucket.

I don't want up to 1M "folders" in the "root path" of the Bucket bc this can be unreadable and unorganized.

I figure to have 6 main folder per each power of 10 in the Document name.

So a root "dir" with folders 0-9. and then each 1 of those has its own 0-9 "sub-folders".

This is intended to make things easier to find (like if using a gui file explorer)

E.g. ...If I'm trying to navigate to a Doc named 340853...I know I then need to access
`3/4/0/8/5/3`

Then - inside that can be all pdfs, jpegs, for the 340853 Doc

Any $0.02 on this? Does it not really matter seeing as S3's "folders" aren't a real concept and that everything is actually just flat.

I heard this is an old common naming pattern convention. Does anybody know what it's called?

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote 0-999999, rather than 000000-999999, so I'm assuming these are actually numbers and not, for example IDs. Why do you want to provide folder-like access to all attachments for records that begin with 340 in 3/4/0/, for example? Is that actually valuable to your users?

Comment: Hi! I edited to specify 000000-999999. So they are actually just numbers coming from an autoincrement ORM in MongoDB. I do have access to the actual _ids of the Docs too.

This will not be valuable to users. The intent is for debugging purposes. Users may put in a ticket and say "I can't find attachments from Doc 340". THen, I know to go to 3/4/0.

Maybe this is overkill considering https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html (see first bullet point)

Comment: If you upload the IDs as is, you can either use the "Find objects by prefix" in the web console, or a simple CLI call like `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/123456 .` to debug things.  I'm not sure how adding the path separators helps anyone.

Comment: If you have multiple files associated with a particular number (eg `340853`), then it would be worth putting them all in one prefix, eg `340853/picture.jpg` and `340853/file.pdf`. However, I would advise _against_ 'navigating' the bucket, since there could be hundreds of thousands of objects and Amazon S3 will only return 1000 at a time. It's fine if you wish to list the contents of a particular Prefix, but don't try to list all objects or all folders -- if you need to 'navigate', then maintain your own index in a database and use it for searching and navigating.

Comment: If you wanted to list all files for IDs beginning 340, it doesn’t really help much if you artificially create a hierarchy such as 3/4/0/ because you can list all objects with prefix 340 as easily as you can those with prefix 3/4/0/. The one place it would make a difference is in the AWS S3 Console so if that’s important to you then you might consider some folder hierarchy. But if not, the typical design would have all files associated with ID 123456 under 123456/.